# ionic build --prod (V4/Angular) not bundling completely?

Tags: angular, ionic-framework

New Ionic V4/Angular project, blank template: running `ionic build --prod` does not seem to be bundling completely. Why all the additional js chunks?
I'm looking to deploy my phone app to web as well - as I have done in the past with Ionic.

```
ionic build --prod
> ng run app:build:production

Date: 2018-10-27T20:36:57.028Z
Hash: 3496014cab8eed5ef39d
Time: 53174ms
chunk {0} common.dfd7af42618f93a6d0dc.js (common) 16.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {1} 1.2d9e57ba514744a9b9c8.js () 852 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {2} 2.4d3882054b4afa97f7d8.js () 4.25 kB  [rendered]
chunk {3} 3.d30911794145a89129e9.js () 420 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {4} 4.d9bc89390bd6d3e65ad5.js () 91.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {5} 5.727048f00dd1823671b6.js () 1.94 kB  [rendered]
chunk {6} runtime.be0152731275d987869a.js (runtime) 6.62 kB [entry] [rendered]
chunk {7} main.4728dcd88e6c90c96aba.js (main) 449 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {8} polyfills.8f80c548ed4252672d3c.js (polyfills) 59.6 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {9} styles.9b928e790c0cd0fbd2cb.css (styles) 16.8 kB [initial] [rendered]
chunk {10} 10.4b8169153a0d652d6abb.js () 2.71 kB  [rendered]
chunk {11} 11.2113396d8a92783cbbd3.js () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {12} 12.386a89155c50d58aa4fe.js () 12.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {13} 13.64967299ea34313f5905.js () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {14} 14.3bd3251d6e2659f9ac75.js () 12.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {15} 15.bde99f0eb3802299cd32.js () 31.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {16} 16.520308a5852c18bcf35c.js () 31.3 kB  [rendered]
chunk {17} 17.f25bdffc7b6455d900b1.js () 11.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {18} 18.1a3bddd1ea51fbe6f68b.js () 11.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {19} 19.074e18a5a34a1fa053d9.js () 17.6 kB  [rendered]
chunk {20} 20.0a90eba3c4f2aedce19d.js () 18 kB  [rendered]
chunk {21} 21.836a911b8d30bc94a7c8.js () 7.26 kB  [rendered]
chunk {22} 22.a9194709e45dff23bdf4.js () 7.26 kB  [rendered]
chunk {23} 23.4cac38495a16244552e2.js () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {24} 24.7d7651e71c7764560ed4.js () 12.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {25} 25.f197404b90f415e9adad.js () 3.96 kB  [rendered]
chunk {26} 26.f130eca694393c939ee2.js () 3.95 kB  [rendered]
chunk {27} 27.3ba598afcfa3705ffd20.js () 12.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {28} 28.ffe41ec822803d6db8f9.js () 13.4 kB  [rendered]
chunk {29} 29.97f9ce928216eeaca045.js () 30 kB  [rendered]
chunk {30} 30.3de4243041074c6417ff.js () 30.1 kB  [rendered]
chunk {31} 31.3f12e242f4e9cce6e8e3.js () 7.64 kB  [rendered]
chunk {32} 32.95ed8dbbec293cd219a0.js () 7.82 kB  [rendered]
chunk {33} 33.67a118271631c8940ab2.js () 9.27 kB  [rendered]
chunk {34} 34.a2437bf8ebc2d5bb3532.js () 9.27 kB  [rendered]
chunk {35} 35.ac0663b048241c718a11.js () 21.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {36} 36.399c97908ad2e1eb214a.js () 21.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {37} 37.87958e41a76b42838e8b.js () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {38} 38.863ed5d38f1e2edb197f.js () 10.5 kB  [rendered]
chunk {39} 39.19d9394b80f30934cd18.js () 24.2 kB  [rendered]
chunk {40} 40.c9186d94b0458daee009.js () 25.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {41} 41.abac55d640f75bf500de.js () 13.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {42} 42.a46b2bbef57bdcb02bf2.js () 14.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {43} 43.044adf3528079241d759.js () 835 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {44} 44.eb2b5db3f0d40a18bee5.js () 842 bytes  [rendered]
chunk {45} 45.c70d120779a3a1c81f52.js () 6.17 kB  [rendered]
chunk {46} 46.b4ff485583fda238da17.js () 6.31 kB  [rendered]
chunk {47} 47.aeb5cab903d0ccf0721e.js () 20 kB  [rendered]
chunk {48} 48.9e18d1170938fb1b6197.js () 20 kB  [rendered]
chunk {49} 49.3c9fef152afffc0adce2.js () 13.8 kB  [rendered]
chunk {50} 50.db5abcac094cd105fceb.js () 14.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {51} 51.91d838e7640c5672f620.js () 5.68 kB  [rendered]
chunk {52} 52.9cf67620d5c60cb87344.js () 5.68 kB  [rendered]
chunk {53} 53.72eac39073f0d9405a1b.js () 12.7 kB  [rendered]
chunk {54} 54.b8204d032df478b29a4b.js () 12.9 kB  [rendered]
chunk {55} 55.371497fc664650fedf46.js () 6.52 kB  [rendered]
chunk {56} 56.3dc6cc33eb9e002955a5.js () 6.79 kB  [rendered]
chunk {57} 57.d94145bf7febb1650210.js () 4.8 kB  [rendered]
```

Ionic info output:

```
    Ionic:

   ionic (Ionic CLI)             : 4.2.1 (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/ionic)
   Ionic Framework               : @ionic/angular 4.0.0-beta.13
   @angular-devkit/build-angular : 0.8.6
   @angular-devkit/schematics    : 0.8.6
   @angular/cli                  : 6.2.6
   @ionic/angular-toolkit        : 1.0.0

Cordova:

   cordova (Cordova CLI) : 8.1.2 (cordova-lib@8.1.1)
   Cordova Platforms     : none
   Cordova Plugins       : no whitelisted plugins (0 plugins total)

System:

   Android SDK Tools : 26.1.1 (/Users/golftocs/Library/Android/sdk)
   ios-deploy        : 1.9.2
   NodeJS            : v10.12.0 (/usr/local/bin/node)
   npm               : 6.4.1
   OS                : macOS High Sierra
   Xcode             : Xcode 10.0 Build version 10A255
```

Thanks.

And this is from angular.json file:

```
"build": {
  "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
  "options": {
    "progress": false,
    "outputPath": "www",
    "index": "src/index.html",
    "main": "src/main.ts",
    "polyfills": "src/polyfills.ts",
    "tsConfig": "src/tsconfig.app.json",
    "assets": [
      {
        "glob": "**/*",
        "input": "src/assets",
        "output": "assets"
      },
      {
        "glob": "**/*.svg",
        "input": "node_modules/@ionic/angular/dist/ionic/svg",
        "output": "./svg"
      }
    ],
    "styles": [
      {
        "input": "src/theme/variables.scss"
      },
      {
        "input": "src/global.scss"
      }
    ],
    "scripts": []
  },
  "configurations": {
    "production": {
      "fileReplacements": [
        {
          "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
          "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
        }
      ],
      "optimization": true,
      "outputHashing": "all",
      "sourceMap": false,
      "extractCss": true,
      "namedChunks": false,
      "aot": true,
      "extractLicenses": true,
      "vendorChunk": false,
      "buildOptimizer": true
    }
  }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not an issue and is working as designed in order to improve performance. Please see this [Github issue/discussion](https://github.com/ionic-team/ionic-cli/issues/3721#issuecomment-435092573).